# Escaping special character considering two character as one

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this string

```
d = "&&hell+lo";
```

I want to prepand `\` before all special characters. SO the expected output i want is

```
\&&hell\+o
```

Here i am doing in two regex but not giving the expected output:

```
rex1 = d.replace(/[+-=&&><!(){}[\]"~*?:\/]/g, "\\$&");
alert(rex1);
rex2 = d.replace(/&{2}/g, "\\$&");
alert(rex2);
```

I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) but could not find how to replace `&&` in the given string.

I want to run this in both javascript and PHP also.

`text.replace(/[+-=><!(){}[\]"~*?:\/]|&&/g, "\\$&")` work fine in JS but if i do

```
$pattern = "/[+-=><!(){}[\]\"~*?:\/]|&&/"; 
echo preg_quote("he+l&&lo", $pattern);
```

in PHP, its not working

Comment: You have put `&&` in a character class. `&&` is not a character. It needs to be outside the character class like in this demo: https://regex101.com/r/pT6dC7/1

Comment: yes it worked. `|&&` was a trick

Comment: will this work in php also because i tried but not working

Comment: In PHP, there is `preg_quote()`.

Comment: i tried `$pattern = "/[+-=><!(){}[\]\"~*?:\/]|&&/";
echo preg_quote("he+l&&lo", $pattern);` but didn't work its not working for `&&`

Comment: Could you please specify the exact ptoblem you have? Why escaping `&&` as `\&&`? Your question is somewhat unclear and this is why I decided to close it. You say *I want to prepand ``\`` before all special characters* and the title says *Escaping special character considering two character as one*. Also, `preg_quote` escapes separate symbols that must be escaped for regex and you can specify more as the second parameter. If you want to replace, use `preg_replace`